# Tauri & Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, tauri

According to the doc on Tauri-website. If I use Next.js, I should add a following statement to the next.config.js > output: "export".

The problem accures if I start building the --release version.
I have some dynamic routes like: vehicles -> page.tsx and [id] -> page.tsx
I have tested everything in browser without Tauri and it works. I use Prisma and fetch my data from db (Mongo). So, if I add Tauri without (output: "export") in next.config, it works, but I cannot build my app. If I add it, then it doesn't work any more. I have this error:

Page "/vehicles/[id]/page" is missing exported function "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.

Alright, I add it and then
I always have another Error: result is not iterable.
code:

```
export default async function VehiclePage({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    const emplData = await getOneVehicle(params.id)
    const content = (
        <div>
            {emplData.id}
        </div>
    )
    return content
}

export async function generateStaticParams({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    const emplData = await getOneVehicle(params.id)
    return emplData
}
```

My data is an Object with Id. I don't iterate it.

Swear to Jesus, I tried everything I could find in web. Nothing helps

Comment: can you explain more about your code? `generateStaticParams` need to return array of your param to simulate all possible page.  for example, the dynamic page is using `id` with value 1,2,3. your `generateStaticParams` should return `[{id:1}.{id:2},{id:3}]` 

Ofc this is just my guess since you didn't explain well enough of your problem

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#returns

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks like a bug from the version 13.5.4 if you take the output:export key/value from the next.config.ts file everything works alright. you may have to wait for the next update where thy might fix the issue or downgrade to use 13.4.* for you to do dynamic static export.

You will find similar complains in this github issue section; [Unexpected behavior when using output: 'export', generateStaticParams(), and export const dynamic](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56253)